# C# long data type unboxing issue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

We can cast `int` to `long`.
Why is the following piece of code gives a run time error.

```
object o = 9;
long i = (long)o;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

I am new to C#.

Comment: What error and where?

Comment: It is giving me InvalidCastException

Comment: `o` is a boxed int, so you first have to unbox to the underlying value type before casting to long `(long)(int)o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [this bit of documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx):

> For the unboxing of value types to succeed at run time, **the item being unboxed must be a reference to an object that was previously created by boxing an instance of that value type**. Attempting to unbox null or a reference to an incompatible value type will result in an InvalidCastException.

So, you have to unbox to `int` first and then convert to `long` (an implicit conversion exists):

```
object o = 9;
long i = (int)o;
```

Answer (score 10):

The existing answers rightly explain why you get an exception, but don't really show what you could do instead. First casting to `int` is the typical answer, but only works if you know that the original value was an `int`. If the original value could be either `int` or `long`, then unboxing as `int` could fail just as well.

The simple way to change your code to something that works is by not attempting to do it yourself. .NET Framework already has a method to do exactly what you want: [`Convert.ToInt64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c5w856c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So just write

```
long i = Convert.ToInt64(o);
```

and let the runtime worry about any internally required intermediate type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Since both int and long are value types, they are copied by value, and not by reference like reference types (e.g. `object`). So `o` is of a reference type, so the int object is stored by reference. In order to put it in a new variable of a value type, you need to have some value which you can actually copy into that.

So you need to cast the object to its actual type (int) first before you can perform a type *conversion* to long:

```
object o = 9;
long i = (long)(int)o;
```

You don’t necessarily need to do the `(long)` though as that happens implicitely when storing the value in the long.

Comment: or you could declare it as :
`object o = 9L`. Which would explicitly declare the `object` as a `long`